# Terraform providers - how would you represent a resource that doesn't have clearly defined CRUD operations?

Tags: terraform

For work I'm learning Go and Terraform. I read in their tutorial [how the different contexts are defined](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/provider-setup?in=terraform/providers#define-coffees-data-resource) but I'm not clear on exactly when these different contexts are called and what triggers them.

From looking at the [Hashicups](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-hashicups/blob/master/examples/main.tf) example it looks like when you put this:

```
resource "hashicups_order" "new" {
  items {
    coffee {
      id = 3
    }
    quantity = 2
  }
  items {
    coffee {
      id = 2
    }
    quantity = 2
  }
}
```

in your Terraform file that is going to go look at `hashicups_order` remove the `hashicups` prefix and look for a resource called order. The order resource provides the following contexts:

```
func resourceOrder() *schema.Resource {
    return &schema.Resource{
        CreateContext: resourceOrderCreate,
        ReadContext:   resourceOrderRead,
        UpdateContext: resourceOrderUpdate,
        DeleteContext: resourceOrderDelete,
```

What isn't clear to me is what triggers each context . From that example it seems like since you are increasing the value of quantity it will trigger the update context. If this were the first run and no previous state existed it would trigger create etc.

However it my case the resource is a server and one API resource I want to present to the user is server power control. However you would never "create/destroy" this resource... or would you? You could read the current power state and you could update the power state but, at least intuitively, you wouldn't create or destroy it. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how this would be modeled in Terraform/Go. I conceptually understand the coffee resource in the example but I'm having trouble making the leap to imagining what that looks like as something like a server power capability or other things without a clear matching to the different CRUD operations.

Comment: There is at least one example in the AWS provider of a resource that can only be managed with read/update, and not create/delete. I thought it was the main_route_table_association, but apparently that was not it. In situations like this, you can write the create and delete functions to add or remove the resource from management, and not necessarily literally create and destroy it. Create and delete do not need to be literal on the infrastructure.

Comment: @MattSchuchard so if I understand correctly create could be something like the process of setting up a redfish API session, update could be changing the power, and delete would be tearing down the session? I could use the forcenew metadata tag to force it to do this under all circumstances?